# cucumber using java - Null pointer exception on executing tests from runner class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

i am getting null pointer execption when executing scenarios from runner class. when i execute from feature file then tests are executed without any error, I am using tags to run the scenarios and i have mentioned the tags in runner class, please let me know what might be the reason.

Runner Class Code:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@CucumberOptions( features={"Features"} ,glue={"project.stepdef"} ,tags = {"@chrome","@smoke"} , format = {"pretty", "html:target/site/cucuber-pretty","json:target/site/cucumber.json"} // ,monochrome = true ) 
public class CucumberRunner 
{ 

}
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi soufrk, thanks but i am not getting null pointer when i run the feature file, i am only getting it when i try and run the Runner class

Comment: could you please paste some code from runner class?

Comment: @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @CucumberOptions(
   features={"Features"}
 ,glue={"project.stepdef"}
 ,tags = {"@chrome","@smoke"}
 , format = {"pretty", "html:target/site/cucuber-pretty","json:target/site/cucumber.json"}
// ,monochrome = true
   )

 public class CucumberRunner {

 }

Comment: Can you please add correctly formatted code to your question. From your comment above it seems you are commenting out (`//`) something in your runner?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some minor tweaks to the `runner` Class as follows:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@CucumberOptions( 
                    features="Features",
                    glue="stepdef",
                    tags = {"@chrome","@smoke"}, 
                    plugin = {"html:target/cucumber-html-report", 
                              "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.text",
                              "json:target/cucumber.json"},
                ) 
public class CucumberRunner {}
```

Comment: Thats how my runner class is but when i posted in the comment it came up as normal text

Comment: @testerautomation I have made certain modification watch closely, else just copy/paste and let me know the status